# Return raw objects from Action methods and convert them to JsonResult before rendering

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

The website that I'm working on is heavily depending on ajax/json and knockout.js. 
I would like to have a lot of my Controllers return view-tailored 'json objects', without wrapping them in a JsonResult when returning the method.

This would mean I could easily composite multiple calls into one parent object, but still be able to call the Actions separately too.

Simplified example:

```
public object Main(int groupId)
{
    var viewModel = new
    {
        Persons    = Employees(groupId),
        Messages   = AllMessages()
    };

    return viewModel;
}

public object Employees(int groupId)
{
    return DatabaseContext.Employees.Where(e => e.GroupId == groupId).ToList();
}

public object AllMessages()
{
    return DatabaseContext.Messages.ToList();
}
```

I was hoping I could capture the returned object in `OnActionExecuted` and at that point wrap the whole result up in a final `JsonResult`.

The result is already converted to a string and captured in a `ContentResult` though.

Any ideas? :) Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer. I'm not going for the solution of von v. because I like to keep the boilerplate as small as possible.

In the end I am trying out the following approach. It seems to work pretty well for now, but I still have to test it in real production.

If anyone has some (security) concerns with this, I'm happy to hear them in the comments.

```
// BaseController
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var returnType = ((ReflectedActionDescriptor)filterContext.ActionDescriptor).MethodInfo.ReturnType;

    // is the returnType not deriving from ActionResult? Automatically wrap it in a JsonResult
    if ( !typeof(ActionResult).IsAssignableFrom(returnType) )
    {
        var result = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.Execute(filterContext, filterContext.ActionParameters);

        filterContext.Result = Json( result );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach on this is to create helper methods for your entity calls. Or if you have those methods already somewhere, they can actually serve as the helper methods. In that manner you can return a list of strongly-typed `Messages` and `Employees` as well as returning your desired parent object. You can then have individual controller methods that returns  json objects. In addition, you can extend the parent viewmodel to return additional fields.

### The Parent ViewModel

```
public class ParentModel {
    public Employee Persons {get;set;}
    public Message Messages {get;set;}
}
```

### The Helper Methods

The beauty of using helper methods similar to what is defined here is that you can apply a few more logic to your query, and more, and you don't have to change anything in your controller methods.

```
public ParentModel GetMain(int groupId)
{
    var viewModel = new ParentModel 
    {
        Persons    = Employees(groupId),
        Messages   = AllMessages()
    };

    return viewModel;
}

public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees(int groupId)
{
    return DatabaseContext.Employees.Where(e => e.GroupId == groupId).ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<Message> AllMessages()
{
    return DatabaseContext.Messages.ToList();
}
```

### The Controller Methods

```
public ActionResult GetParent(int groupId){
    return Json(helperinstance.GetMain()); 
}
public ActionResult GetEmployees(int groupId){
    return Json(helperinstance.Employees()); 
}
public ActionResult GetMessages(int groupId){
    return Json(helperinstance.AllMessages()); 
}
```